# Produce high-contrast numbers on un-painted dice?

Tags: dice

I picked up some [Gamescience](http://www.gamestation.net/GameScience-Coal-Black-Precision-Dice/M/B001D6FLKO.htm) d20s based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/what-is-the-best-place-to-get-quality-polyhedral-dice).  I got the black ones.  They are very shiny!

Of course, they are unpainted.  How can I paint/ink/color the numbers to get very high contrast between the numbers and the die?

Comment: You realize, paint will add a slight bias to Lou Zocchi's perfectly balanced dice... ;) ETA: Okay, so that's probably not true. They're designed with inking in mind.

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble with marking their transparent dice as black marker doesn't have enough contrast.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nothing silly about white crayon!  There's something to be said for tradition...

Answer (score 40):

I experimented with the methods proposed (except liquid white-out; couldn't find any), with the following results:

**Paint:**  I used acrylic paint to fill in the numbers and paper towel to remove the excess.  Very good opacity with this method, but I could not get enough paint to stay in the numbers during the removal of the excess.  I tried various drying times before removing the excess, but could not get the results I wanted.  Maybe another type of paint would work better?

**Marker:**  I used Sharpie ultra-fine point white marker.  My hands are not as steady as they used to be, so I had a hard time getting a neat and tidy finished appearance.  The markings were not very opaque and did not provide great contrast.  (I'm guessing that black marker on light colored dice would provide much better results.)

**Crayon:**  I experimented with several brands and types of crayon.  Crayola seems to work the best, probably because of the higher quality wax, which is softer and clings in the grooves of the numbers better.  Specifically the Crayola GelFX crayons worked the best.  They are made for writing on black paper, so the pigments are **very** opaque, and the wax is very soft and sticky; really stays in the numbers.  Time will tell if it holds up to heavy use.

Below is an image of two of the dice filled with Crayola GelFX 'Spring Green' and 'Tickle Me Pink'.  (The girls thought white was booooring).

[image]

---

## **Update**

(2012-July-26)

It's coming up on 2 years now (21 months) since I used the crayon on these dice.  They have had moderate to heavy use in that time.  The color has shown no signs of wear or fading, and it is staying in the numbers right where I put it.

**Conclusion:  Crayola Gel FX crayons are the way to go.  Color goes on easy, fills well, and is very opaque.**

Comment: If you fill in the number with something like crayon, isn't that going to defeat the purpose of buying precision dice, since the weight will no longer be evenly distributed?

Comment: @EugeneKatz The precision in the sharpness of the edges is more important for the design than the slight variation due to lost material. They're not originally specially weighted to compensate for the difference between the material removed for '1' versus for '20' anyway. (That would take a ridiculously expensive manufacturing process.) Note that casino dice have filled pips for this very reason—it *restores* the balance of the die. Crayon is thus likely better than pen for this.

Comment: Gel FX _crayons_ or **markers**? I can't find Gel FX _crayons_ anywhere (online or in stores).

Comment: @javafueled:  Crayons.  I suppose it's possible that they don't make them anymore.  Basically, you want a nice soft crayon that is made for use on black paper.  That way, the pigment is very opaque.

Comment: The following two products might be acceptable substitutes for Gel FX:  http://www.crayola.com/products/dryerase-bright-crayons-product/, http://www.crayola.com/products/16-ct-metallic-fx-crayons-regular-size-product/, but I haven't tested either one.

Comment: I have the dry erase set. Very good results. Though I'm also interested in whether the Crayola Gel FX you have (if you still have them) are "water soluble." My research suggests that the Gel FX **crayons** are/were a Crayola mass-market choice where customers might also be looking at Faber Castell's Gelato series. Gelato's appear to be water soluble, which would not seem to be suited for gaming environments or your experience with "endurance."

Comment: I don't still have the box the Crayolas came in.  Though I can tell you that when an art supply like that says 'water soluble', they generally mean, "if you scrub really hard with soap and water, it might not stain your clothes".  The Crayola Gel FX have proven impervious to incidental spills, and I remember that I had a deuce of a time getting it all off my fingers when I was first coloring the dice; though soap and water and scrubbing did work for clean-up, so they would still technically be described as water soluble.

Answer (score 8):

White grease pencil.  Rub the sides until the grease pencil fills in the numbers.  Then wipe with a soft cloth so all that shows in white is the number.

Answer (score 7):

I used a silver metallic ink sharpie on my GameScience black dice and they came out really well.

Comment: I did the same about 25 years ago on a d6, it still looks fine...

Answer (score 6):

We used liquid white-out, it is incredibly high contrast. Can you still get that stuff? :-) We used nail-polish remover (acetone) as a thinner to remove the excess.

Comment: After you've used whiteout to fill in all the numbers, scrape a knife blade along the surface of the die to scratch away all the excess whiteout that gets outside the number. This is both slightly harmful to the blade (use a blade you don't care about as much) and will produce minor scratches in your die (won't affect rolling).

Comment: Nice tip @lokathor. I remember using thinner, so I'll amend my answer as well...

Comment: As a side note, nail polish remover is also great for getting paint or glue off of a metal miniature (don't use it on plastic minis, it will start melting the mini)

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://jrients.blogspot.com/2009/08/inking-gamescience-dice.html) and [here](http://carmensminiaturepainting.blogspot.com/2009/05/off-beaten-path-painting-dice.html):

> The traditional technique is to rub a crayon repeatedly across the number and then wipe away the considerable excess with a tissue or paper towel. That's why old boxed sets use to come with crayons.

(but that way is silly)

First, wash the dice. Then use a fine brush to ink the numbers with white paint, then quickly use a paper towel to wipe off the excess.

Comment: Every time I've tried this I've made a horrific mess.  Probably because I'm completely spastic at fine manipulation.

Comment: I use crayon, which works well enough.  Is there a particular kind of paint you'd recommend?

Comment: The first link from Jeff Rients.  I would not recommend trying that.  I did, it worked out nice, but the marker rubbed off after a couple sessions.

Comment: I saw a post somewhere where they recommended using your finger instead of paper.  The paper tends to pull the paint out of the figures, and doesn't do a good job of cleaning the face.  Your fingerprint just squeegees the paint off, leaving you with a finger that needs cleaning...but good looking dice.

Answer (score 5):

I used miniatures paint most recently on some new black Gamescience dice.  As others attest, paper towel just smears paint everywhere and sucks the paint out of the numbers.  Turns out that there is a simple solution: use your fingers.  When I switched to using my fingers, I quickly got clean faces and paint filled numbers.  On the down side, my fingers were painty, but with water soluble paint it cleaned up easily.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the stuff that is made for the job:

One brand, called Lacquer-Stik, is available from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BXJ906) or [Brownells](http://www.brownells.com/.aspx/pid=7778/Product/LACQUER_STIK_reg_).  Check the prices and color availability before you order.  Or, check around a little on your own.  Those were just the first two places I found when I [searched](http://www.google.com/search?q=Lacquer-Stik).

It comes in black, gold and bright colors.  It's inexpensive and permanent.

Comment: Thanks for link.  Sadly, it doesn't come in Spring Green or Tickle-Me-Pink. :)  I've got some other uses that would be perfect for that,  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Get an ultra-fine or extra-fine white-ink permanent marker or paint marker. Your local drafting supply company should have them for about $10 each or less.

Use this to very carefully write inside the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I had bad luck painting the Gamescience dice with miniature paints.  My errors stuck to the dice and smudged when I tried to remove them.  I didn't have this problem fixing up chessex dice.

Depending on the color of the dice, mechanical pencil is not unreasonable.  It's pretty shiny and it's hard to screw up.  Not as bright as actual paint though.